# Copy text from a PDF document with phonetic alphabet included

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, conversion, documents, file-conversion

I have a long list of vocabularies in a PDF document where the foreign words are also shown in phonetic spelling, like this:

el chico [ˈtʃiko]

Now, I have to copy the everything into a different document (a text document or Excel), but the phonetic alphabet isn't copied properly.

Now, when I copy the above word from the PDF & paste it into a different document I get this:

el chico ['tSiko]

Or instead of this one:
don, doña [dɔn, ˈdoɲa]

After the copy & paste the result is this:
don, doña [dOn, 'do®a]

Can someone give me an idea how to copy & paste the content from the PDF into a different document format, without writing every single phonetic character?

I'm using a Mac.

Comment: Could be a fonts thing?  Check that the fonts in the pdf (Properties/Fonts in adobe) exist on your pc and install them if they don't.